# Вопрос по iframe и javascript...

Tags: ajax, javascript

На сервере есть скрипт http://site.ru/iframe.php, которому передается get параметр текущей страницы. Как при помощи iframe и javascript открывать страницу следующего плана: http://site.ru/iframe.php?url=адрес-текущей страницы (адрес текущей страницы должен передаваться включая локальный просмотр. например, просматривая фрейм локально: http://site.ru/iframe.php?url=file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/test/test.html?test=test)

Answer (score 1):

Считывайте текущий адрес из алресной строки (window.location.href) и с помошью js подставляйте его в параметр src iframe`а

Comment: локально не получается. выдает blank